# Repeating a function every x seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to repeat the function "refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow)" every x seconds but it won't work. Below is what the code that i have tried in html and javascript. Any help given is appreciated.

I am trying to repeat the function "refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow)" every x seconds but it won't work. Below is what the code that i have tried in html and javascript. Any help given is appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
function initMap() {
       
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  

        
        myAddress = document.getElementById("address"); 
    

      function refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
       
   $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: 'http://localhost/scripts/retrievegeolocation.php',
     dataType: "json",
           success: function(data)
           {
      
               document.getElementById("Lat").innerHTML = data.Lat; // show response from the php script.
      document.getElementById("Lng").innerHTML = data.Lng;
      
    
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(data.Lat), lng: parseFloat(data.Lng)};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
     
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(15);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,icon:'http://localhost/img/car.png',
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
     
     myAddress.innerHTML="Address: " + results[0].formatted_address;
    
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
           }
  
         });

  
}
```

```html
   <br/><center> LAT : <p id="Lat"  name="Lat" value="    "></p></center><br/>
    

  <center>LNG : </center>
  <center><p id="Lng" name="Lng" value="    "></p></center>
   
    <center><p style="font-size:20px;" id="address"></p></center> 

<button onclick="function() {
   refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow);
}">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Your code snippet isn't even working.

Comment: have you tried using javascript interval function

Comment: i used setInterval (function,delay) and it does not work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are missing a closing parenthesis for the function `initMap()`

I have removed all the code inside and called the dummy functions. It is working fine. Below is the code snippet. Copy paste this into browser console to run this.

```
function initMap() {

    function refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow) {  
        alert(' refresh');  
    }
    setInterval(refresh, 1000);
    }
initMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button that is calling `refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow)` doesn't know what geocoder, map, or infowindow are. Two of those items are instantiated inside the `initMap()` function which is presumably the async loading Google javascript's callback function and map was never instantiated.

Assuming you have an element with the id of "map", put `var map = document.getElementById("map");` close to the top of the initMap() function and then try adding this code within the initMap() function after you declare the refresh function.

```
setInterval( function() {
    refresh(geocoder, map, infowindow);
}, 20 );
```